# The word for a man who hunts a dangerous mountain cat without prophylactic?

Tags: vocabulary

Hello once again special team stack exchange and a usage.

I search many hours dictionary for a man goes into woods for hunt dangerous mountain cat or similar enemy despite no protection or prophylactic caution. Maybe he take only small catpalt for kill crow or moose. So when cat comes he catch him with no pants.

Sorry my friends. I need to clear that man think his tool is bigger than reality it is. So the word is not reckless for this man.

Comment: This question also needs to go into the EL&U hall of fame. Please, for the sake of posterity, no one edit it!

Comment: [Highly relevant here.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732)

Comment: Also, are you saying that this rather stupid hunter also went into the woods _without wearing trousers_?!? What possible language on earth would have a word for this?

Comment: @Janus, the [Darwin Award Committee](http://www.darwinawards.com) simply calls them *laureates*.

Comment: Funny. But clearly trolling.

Comment: Here he is: Bolgaff <The Mad Hunter> http://cata-shoot.tauri.hu/?npc=47003

Comment: @Josh, I count *six* kinds of pants and *zero* catpalts in that guy's inventory. No, no reckless hunter he.

Comment: There _must_ be a word for this. Whatever you think the size of your tool is, you should not let your decision to bring a prophylactic depend on that. Unless (you think) the size of your tool prohibits the use of a prophylactic.

Comment: Come on, is *no one* going to make a joke about "[*hunting cougars*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cougar)", "*using protection*", and being caught with your pants down? Really? I have to do everything around here!

Comment: @DanBron: well, I have to admit I hadn't even caught on to the cougars yet. Shame on me!

Comment: Well, cats don't wear pants, so there's that.

Comment: I can’t quite decide whether this would be banned or applauded in Russia … is it pro-LGBTQ propaganda, or anti-LGBTQ propaganda? So ambiguous.

Comment: Don't you need a crowpalt or a moosepalt for killing those?

Comment: I think if there were special words for such things as you describe the OED would have five volumes instead of one.

Comment: Sorry to have removed the original context for many of the above comments capitalising on the (unintended?) innuendo. But I've edited out all the irrelevant references to prophylactics and cocksure tool-wielding.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I've rolled back your edits, because [it also breaks the most-upvoted answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is trolling

Comment: @DanBron Look at the OPs other questions, well written and clear. This is clearly a joke.

Comment: @TankorSmash Yes, I know. As are 90% of the comments and half the answers to it! We all know. That doesn't mean [we don't welcome jokes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/), sometimes. Note that despite the obvious humor, it's managed to net 14 upvotes, *16 stars*, and all the answers have positive scores, totalling nearly 50 upvotes all told. Forget about the votes on comments!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe it's a bit trolling, but I had a good laugh! It reminds me of how many Germans (like me) speak English in a very stupid way sometimes. For example: "Again what learned" or "overheadnothing". That's English which only Germans can understand.

Comment: I just look to SE for a reference to whatever I'm looking for. I don't expect to find a joke in a dictionary, is what I'm getting at. There's other forums for jokes. IE reddit, twitter, ED. Fun is good, but fun is cheap and easy to find. Quality content isn't. I could be in the minority.

Comment: @TankorSmash In short, I, personally, do find this to be *quality content*. It's on-topic satire, and really funny if you're a denizen of EL&U and familiar with its culture and patterns. And Medica's perfectly in-voice and double-entendre-laced response is sublime. In other words, *this* kind of fun is *not* easy to find.

Comment: @DanBron That's a good and fair point, I suppose so long as it's far and few between it's not really a problem. Still though, my vote is definitely in 0 tolerance.

Comment: @TankorSmash, "So long as it's few and far between" appears to be the [official SE policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).  No matter now, the question has been closed (and we've already wrung all the humor out of it) anyway.

Comment: @TankorSmash: Most if not all of the "jocular" definitions have been culled in successive new editions, but I've had Chambers for many decades. The first one I found myself as a teenager was: [***éclair** - 'a cake long in shape but short in duration'*](http://www.crossword.org.uk/chambers.htm), but years later I enjoyed being told about ***baby-sitter** - 'one who mounts guard over a baby to relieve the usual attendant'*.

Comment: I was going to suggest "Mountain man". They are usually trappers or they use simple weapons. They might encounter a puma and fight it off. You might see them pantless! (not sure about the last one)

Comment: Just in case others are misled: this is a joke/troll account that asks silly and deliberately disingenuous questions that nonetheless require a bit of lateral thinking to locate the actual jokes.

Answer (score 30):

I might call this man [*overconfident*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overconfident):

> Excessively confident; presumptuous; foolhardy. Also cocky, cocksure, overweening. Also, (informal) *too big for one's britches.*

[*cocksure*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cocksure)

> too certain; overconfident: He was so cocksure he would catch the cougar that he that he didn't even bother to wear pants.

Comment: +1 for cocksure. Your example sentence really nails the situation!

Comment: I think it's quite common to go into [The Woods](https://www.thewoodscampground.com) without wearing pants, and you'll be *especially* welcome if you're too big for your britches.

Comment: @DanBron - this is just too rich. :D

Comment: @DanBron I especially love the discreet little ad at the bottom right for _bearguide.net_. :-D

Comment: @medica, I had to *something* to repay you for this unbelievably brilliant answer. *Overweening*!

Comment: +1.  A definitive answer to an important question we've all had at one time or another.

Comment: Speaking of *cocksure*, you might consider *ballsy*.

Answer (score 9):

I think it could be said that the hunter is [hubristic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hubristic).

If there's a more precise word for this situation in another language it should be incorporated into English forthwith.

Comment: Patrick, I think the sense the OP is looking for is more like *hubba-hubba-hubristic*!

Answer (score 9):

The word you're looking for is *inebriated*. While *inebriated*, a person is often likely to attempt daring and dangerous feats, and to consider it a good idea to make such an attempt without their pants.

Answer (score 3):

I would call such man a **reckless** hunter.

Or, if he thinks that his tool is bigger than it is in reality, an **overconfident** hunter.

Comment: But he *brought catpalt for kill crow or moose*. Surely that's at least partially reckful?

Comment: @DanBron: I found no definition for *catpalt*, hence I cannot reck fully the extent of his reckfulness.

Comment: I think the man brought a "CATSPAW" to kill a (small) crow or MOUSE. But in any event, a smaller weapon than sported by most "cats."

Comment: @TomAu, I think the hunter actually brought a *slingshot*, which the author confused with a *catapult*, but correcting the words misses the point entirely.

Comment: @DanBron: (The future King) David killed lions with slingshots. Not to mention Goliath. If the man had brought a slingshot, that would have been "unconventional," but not necessarily foolhardy, depending on his level of skill.

Comment: @Tom, yeah, but those feats were so impressive, and successful despite such long odds, that his fierce reputation was built upon them (partially, at least).